# How to resolve wamp issue with Magento 2.2.7

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.7, wamp

I have installed wamp 3.0.8 for 32 bit Windows 10 OS in my laptop. And I have downloaded Magento 2.2.7. While hitting http://localhost:8080/magento I am getting this error. Please help me to solve the issue or give guidance to get magento in my Laptop with WAMP.[image]

Comment: Did you run composer update through cli?

Comment: change your Magento directory attributes, uncheck the read only attribute then apply to all

Comment: @magefms .. please explain me how to do that

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Directory permission (Attribute), your Magento root directory has a **Read Only attribute.**

Try to change it by unchecking the Read Only Attribute in the properties of your Magento Directory.
After changing, try running upgrade again and redeploy static view files.

Comment: how to do the second point?

Comment: just right click on your Magento installation folder then click properties, then uncheck Read-only , then click apply changes to subfolder and files